# Axios then function also does catch?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

My post is successful, but I can't do anything in the then statement except console.log(); it always jumps to the catch.

```
axios.post('/group/15/discussion/'+ this.discussion.id+ '/schedule',this.form, {handleErrors:true})
                    .then(function(response) {
                        //this.form.valid = true;
                        console.log("success");

                        console.log('set form valid');
                        this.$refs['schedule-group-discussion-'+this.id].hide();
                        console.log('close modal');
                        /*this.$emit('updateDiscussion',response.data.discussion);
                        this.$toast.success(response.data.message,'Success!',{icon: 'fas fa-check-circle'});*/
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log("catch");
                        this.form.valid = false;
                    });
```

here is my console log in order:
success
set form valid
catch

What is wrong?

Comment: Your POST response status code 200?

Comment: yes, it does have code 200

Comment: Based on the console log output, you can assume that this this.$refs['schedule-group-discussion-'+this.id].hide(); produces an error. Have you tried to inspect/log the catched error?

Comment: @DavidHorák yes, and you are right. it says "this" is undefined/

Comment: @JasonSpick here you go, the issue is not related to axios but rather to undefined reference, that should be simple to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your scope of `this`. You're actually getting an error, `cannot read property valid of undefined`, but you didn't `console.log(error)`. You need to use the `fat arrow function` in your `.then()` as well:

```
.then(function(response) {
```

to

```
.then((response) => {
```

Now `this` is scoped correctly.